# Finding the maximal convex function below a given one

Tags: python, algorithm, convex-hull

I have a vector  X of arguments and Y of values, both length n vectors of floats. I need to construct a vector such that (X, Yc) is a graph of a maximal convex function satisfying Yc <= Y pointwise. A naive algo that comes to my mind is O(n^2) in time, so I'm looking for something faster than that.

In math that's something we call a convex hull problem, so I have tried finding any lib in python that will do this, but they all seem to be focused on 2d or 3d problems. Any suggestions what would be the fastest way for me to find Yc?

What I have tried: I can use a `scipy.spatial` library to compute the 2d convex hull

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(1, 5, 9)
Y = np.array([2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 1, 4, 3])

points = np.column_stack((X, Y))
hull = ConvexHull(points)

print("Indices of points forming the convex hull:", hull.vertices)

plt.plot(X, Y, 'o')
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'k-')
plt.show()
```

which produces the following plot:

[image]

however, the vector Yc I need is the lower boundary of this plot, and I am not sure what's the easiest way to obtain it.

Comment: This is rather straightforward convex hull application, isn't it? You just need to calculate the convex hull and take the lower part of it. There are even algorithms that calculate lower and upper parts separately.

Comment: One of the best algorithms for the nth-dimensional case for the convex hull problem is the Quickhull algorithm that is actually O(n^2) worst case. So unless you have something to exploit in your problem, I'm unsure you'll find something much faster.

Comment: @AnilCh I don't understand where you get n-dimensional case, I understand that OP's case is n points is 2D. In this case, Graham algorithm runs in O(n log n)

Comment: @AnilCh in your comment n is from the dimension or from the number of points?

Comment: @Petr thanks, I am not familair with using such algos. If you could provide more guidance, that would be nice. fwiw, X is sorted in my case

Comment: @Petr You're right, my bad, I thought it was nth dimensional case. OP, scipy has a built-in convex hull algorithm with Qhull. You also can find gists in github for the Graham Scan algorithm made in python.

Comment: @AnilCh scipy gives me a subset of points and their ordering that corresponds to the vertices and the boundary of the convex hull. To go from there to a vector Yc does not sound like the most trivial problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need the lowest half of the convex hull. The part shown in green on the picture below:

[image]

For this, you simply build a convex hull. The convex hull will always include the leftmost and the rightmost points of your set, and those points will divide your hull into two halves. So you find these points in the convex hull, and split the hull into two halves. (One of the halves could wrap around the end of your convex hull array.) Then you need to find which half is the lowest, this can be done by many approaches, the simplest will be to calculate the average y coordinate of the two halves and choose the half that has lower average.

Also, it is possible to implement Graham algorithm so that it will directly produce the lowest half (and some implementations of the algorithm do indeed to this). You sort the points by x coordinate, and then do a simple stack-based pass. The pseudocode (adapted from Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan):

```
# The pseudocode below uses a function ccw: 
# ccw > 0 if three points make a counter-clockwise turn, 
# clockwise if ccw < 0, and collinear if ccw = 0.
# The ccw function can usually be implemented via a vector cross product

let points be the list of points
let stack = empty_stack()

sort points by x coordinate

for point in points:
    # pop the last point from the stack if we turn clockwise to reach this point
    while count stack > 1 and ccw(next_to_top(stack), top(stack), point) <= 0:
        pop stack
    push point to stack
end
```

In any case, you will need to somehow treat the situations when there are several leftmost or rightmost points. The exact treatment will depend on the details of your problem; because you need only the lowest half, the simplest approach will be just drop all leftmost points except the lowest of them, and similarly with the rightmost points.

Comment: Thanks! as I have mentioned in the OP, X are the arguments, hence leftmost and rightmost points are unique. Yet, I'm still not sure how to go from the list of points to the vector Yc, which for every x in X should provide some value yc.

Comment: @SBF, ah, so you need intermediate values. Then this is just a question of linear interpolation

Comment: indeed, but how for a given `i = 1 ... len(X) - 1` can I get `j < i` and `k > i` which to use for interpolation?

Comment: @SBF, use binary search for example. Or I'm sure that python should have some library that, given a set of points (X, Y) with increasing X, will return the interpolated value of y for ant intermediate x

Comment: so what you're saying: once I get the list of vertex indices, I need to find it's part that goes between the leftmost and rightmost points. There will be two parts, I need to understand which one the lower one. Then going over that part in a certain direction (the points will be sorted in some way), I just linearly interpolate all intermediate points. Is that correct?

Comment: @SBF, yes, you're right

Comment: thanks, that's a bit far from a comprehensive solution, so I'll wait if anything else is suggested. otherwise I'll accept your answer

Comment: @SBF, well, SO is not a code writing service, it's about removing any specific stumbling blocks you may have. Writing code is your task :)